# Validate CSV file according to data in header in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, csv, django-forms

In my Django admin i am uploading a CSV file and downloading it. i have two columns Test case ID and Summary.

```
Test Case ID,Summary

TC-1,Verify that Process CSV sub module is displayed under “Process CSV” module on Dashboard of Client’s user.
TC-2,Verify that Process CSV sub module is displayed under “Process CSV” module on Dashboard of Client’s user.
TC-3,Verify the dashboard.
TC-4,“verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding “new category records” using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'”
TC-5,“verify that user is able to update 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding “new category records” using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'”
```

I want to add a validation like if the data under Test Case ID is empty the should be error message "All Summaries should  have respective Test Case ID'
I have added validation for headers .like if header is not present but don't know how to add validation for data under the respective headers.

Forms.py

```
class CsvUpload(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField()

    def clean_csv_file(self):
        # Probably worth doing this check first anyway
        value = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
        if not value.name.endswith('.csv'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid file type')
        try:
            data = pd.read_csv(
                value.file, encoding='ISO-8859-1', engine='python')
            
            data.columns = data.columns.str.strip().str.lower()
            data = data.rename(columns={'test case id': 'Test Case ID'})

            def transform(df):
                my_new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9"''-_“” \n\.]', '', df)
                return my_new_string

            data['summary'] = data['summary'].apply(transform)

        except KeyError:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'CSV file must have "Summary" column and "Test Case ID" column')

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error while parsing CSV file=> %s', e)
            raise forms.ValidationError('Failed to parse the CSV file')

        return data

def csv_content_validator(csv_file):
    # Probably worth doing this check first anyway
    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid file type')

    decoded_file = csv_file.read().decode('ISO-8859-1').splitlines()
    reader = csv.DictReader(decoded_file)
    headers = []
    # for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    for row in reader:
        headers = [x.lower() for x in list(row.keys())]
        break

    if 'summary' not in headers or 'test case id' not in headers:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'CSV file must have "Summary" column and "Test Case ID" column')

class AICSVFileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    file = forms.FileField(
        validators=[csv_content_validator]
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['file'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['threshold'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['threshold'].label = "Duplicacy Level"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        obj = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.original_filename = obj.file.name
        obj.save()
        return obj

    class Meta:
        model = AICSVFile
        fields = ['file', 'threshold']
```